# Javascript is not attaching to the DOM

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gwt, uibinder, gwt-bootstrap, gwtbootstrap3

I have got one issue here. I am using bootstrap css and gwt in my application.
In my uibinder page, I am using gwt textbox, and applying a style ("date") as shown below.

```
<g:TextBox styleName="span11 date"></g:TextBox>
```

Also bootstrap-datepicker.js and related bootstrap css files have been attached. On loading of a html, I am running the below script.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.date').datepicker({
        format: 'm/d/yyyy',
        showWeek: true,
        startDate: 'today',
        autoclose: true,
      });
});
```

Still bootstrap datepicker popup is not coming on focus of a gwt textbox.

Also, I tried the otherway round, by injecting the js file and using JSNI approach.

Still it didn't worked..

Also, when I open the browser console (using F12), and paste the above javascript snippet, it works fine.

Is there anything settings/configurations needs to be done?

Is GWT is blocking the javascript execution???

Any suggestions would be appreciated!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Bootstrap in your GWT application, I'd strongly suggest using the existing libraries like [gwtbootstrap3](https://github.com/gwtbootstrap3/gwtbootstrap3) or [gwt-bootstrap](https://github.com/gwtbootstrap/gwt-bootstrap).

The problem here is probably due to the fact that the `TextBox` has not been added to the DOM yet. All the scripts might have been loaded, but that doesn't mean the whole view has been build by GWT (try adding a delay in that function to see if I'm right). You could add a "callback" method in your view (called when the view is available) that will invoke a method in your host page that will convert the `TextBox` to a `datepicker`... But unless that's the only widget in your application that you are using from Bootstrap, I'd suggest using a proper library that imports Bootstrap's widgets in a more GWT way.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you include your

```
<script src=".nocache.js"></script>
```

**before**

```
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```